# Visualization Tools for Networks that Change with Time

Tags: linux, networking

Does anyone known of any good Linux tools for visualizing networks that change (quickly) with time.

I'm interested in things like:

- Routes between nodes
- Delays between nodes (especially as they change with time)
- Throughput

I have root access to all the nodes (so I can run daemons on them all).  Also, assume that I either have a management network that is stable or I will collect data and then analyze it offline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/) runs on a LAMP stack has both [manual](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Maps) and [automatic](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Automatic_Map_Creation) mapping capability. I can't say it is trivial to setup up, but it's an incredibly flexible and featureful platform with a very active community. You could setup [Threshold Alerts](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Thresholding) for things like latency between nodes, dropped routes, lost paths, etc.

[image: OpenNMS Mapping]

---

Zenmap (the GUI version the famous namp) has a nice topology mapping feature. Although, it will only generate a one time map and will not automatically update or give you threshold alerting. It will however, with five minutes worth of time, give you a quick and dirty topology map.

[image: zenmap topo]

Answer (score 2):

The best way to analyze that is imho to look at the statistic counters of the network devices involed (switches/routers).

This is called netflow analysis - there seem to be free and commercial tools around for this.